# twenty Seventeen mobile menu

Tags: wordpress, themes

I have WordPress website with twenty seventeen theme. Menu work well on desktop but when website load on mobile the menu it automatically brings the menu up after loading when scroll website menu close into single toggle. When I click a menu item, the page redirect on new page with same problem.
Pic attached for reference.
I'll be very grateful if some assist me who to solve this.

[image]

maybe this is the code:
// Set the active submenu initial state.

```
    container.find( '.current-menu-ancestor > .sub-menu' ).addClass( 'toggled-on' );

    container.find( '.dropdown-toggle' ).on( 'click', function( e ) {
        var _this = $( this ),
            screenReaderSpan = _this.find( '.screen-reader-text' );

        e.preventDefault();
        _this.toggleClass( 'toggled-on' );
        _this.next( '.children, .sub-menu' ).toggleClass( 'toggled-on' );

        _this.attr( 'aria-expanded', _this.attr( 'aria-expanded' ) === 'false' ? 'true' : 'false' );

        screenReaderSpan.text( screenReaderSpan.text() === twentyseventeenScreenReaderText.expand ? twentyseventeenScreenReaderText.collapse : twentyseventeenScreenReaderText.expand );
    });
}
```

Comment: please let me know if need more details

Comment: post code your code

Comment: This is default menu provided my theme.

Comment: tell me if this is not the following code

Comment: Its working fine without customization. what you customized in this theme?

Comment: added search bar only for mobile devices..

Comment: but I'm facing this issue before customization of theme.

Comment: comment this line and check `container.find( '.current-menu-ancestor > .sub-menu' ).addClass( 'toggled-on' );`

Comment: commend that line of code but issue not resolve